# Create an absolute path from a relative path using the Windows api (c++)

Tags: c++, windows, directory

How can I simplify a path that contains relative folder references to an absolute path? For example, simplify `"C:\windows\temp\..\..\windows"` to `"C:\Windows"`. FWIW, I'm using the Windows C++ API in an MFC application, but I don't need an MFC-specific solution.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcanonicalizea

Comment: Though from reading the doc page for the first time in a long time, it looks like we want to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathcchcanonicalizeex instead. Never stop keeping up, folks. I got me some code to fix.

Comment: Or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical

Comment: Woo! Cross platform portability. Hopefully I'll be allowed to use C++17 at work in less time than it took to get C++11 cleared.

Comment: All three suggestions were good. I ended up using PathCanonicalize() as suggested by user4581301.  If they add it as a solution I'll give 'em credit. Otherwise, I'll likely answer my own question so it isn't left open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three suggestions in the comments were were good. I ended up using PathCanonicalize() as suggested by user4581301 (I'd give him credit, but he posted the answer as a comment).